# Unable to boot into WIndows after resizing partition, IO1_INITIALIZATION_FAILED

Tags: ubuntu, boot, partitioning, windows-11

I dual boot between Ubuntu and Windows 11

After increasing my Windows partition size with GParted, I am unable to boot into Windows. It boots in to a blue screen giving the stop code IO1_INITIALIZATION_FAILED. Startup repair as well as boot-repair did not fix the issue. Trying to boot into safe mode gives the same error. I noticed that diskpart in command prompt shows that my previously C partition (with Windows) is now D and another partition is C. How do I fix this?

[Paste from boot-repair](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/WdD94gRRQP/)

Comment: Your “paste” isn’t accessible